# Using a variable in a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I need to clean up the users table and several related tables.  So I create a variable that contains the userids and I want to use those values instead of using a sub-query for each delete statement.

I get a syntax error with this. What am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `DBNAME`.`SP_PURGE_DISABLED_USERS` ()
BEGIN
  select userid into @disabled_users from USERS where disabled=1;
  delete from USER_ACTIVITY where userid in SELECT userid FROM @disabled_users;
  delete from USER_PREFS where userid in SELECT userid FROM @disabled_users;
  -- <snip> several other related tables to be cleaned up
  delete from USERS where userid in SELECT userid FROM @disabled_users;
END
```

Comment: if your select returns multiple rows then you can use a cursor. I cite from [manual, SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) : _The query should return a single row. If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code 1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged. If the query returns multiple rows, error 1172 occurs (Result consisted of more than one row)_

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, at the end of your procedure you need to put your delimiter:

```
 END$$
```

Then reset you're delimiter back to `;`

```
 DELIMITER ;
```

In the procedure, your delete statements don't make sense.   I'd stop using the parameter to store the results of the select and an inner select:

```
delete from USER_ACTIVITY 
       WHERE userid in ( select userid from users where disabled=1 );
```

If you only have a realatively small set of disabled users to delete, you could use group concat and find in set:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `DBNAME`.`SP_PURGE_DISABLED_USERS` ()
BEGIN
  select GROUP_CONCAT(userid) into @disabled_users from USERS where disabled=1;
  delete from USER_ACTIVITY where  FIND_IN_SET(userid, @disabled_users);
  delete from USER_PREFS where FIND_IN_SET(userid, @disabled_users);
  -- <snip> several other related tables to be cleaned up
  delete from USERS where FIND_IN_SET(userid, @disabled_users);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I wouldn't do this with many thousands of userid's though... there may be a limit to string length in a variable.

Comment: The problem with the subquery is that mysql does a full table scan each time it is called.  I see the same performance issue happening with the join.  The example code is a very simplified version of what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: @EdManet If you do this frequently you could avoid the scan with an index on disabled (and userid if it's not the PK)

Comment: @EdManet if you really want to only use a single select to get the userid's to delete, you'll probably need cursors: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cursors.html

Comment: @EdManet Ok, I figured a crazy way to use group concat and find in set to avoid doing multiple subqueries... updating the answer.

Comment: Yeah... that doesn't seem like it would help performance.  I'm going to try a temporary table and see if that does it.

Comment: @EdManet Honestly, the index and subquery is the way to go with this or a 'delete join', but I can never remember the syntax...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with a temporary table. It cut the stored procedure execution time in half.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DBNAME`.`SP_PURGE_DISABLED_USERS` ()
BEGIN
  create temporary table disabled_users 
    as (select userid from USERS where disabled=1);
  delete from USER_ACTIVITY where userid in SELECT userid FROM disabled_users;
  delete from USER_PREFS where userid in SELECT userid FROM disabled_users;
  -- <snip> several other related tables to be cleaned up
  delete from USERS where userid in SELECT userid FROM disabled_users;
  drop table disabled_users;
END
```

Thanks to all who helped on this question.